# Rails Redirect After Delete Using DELETE Instead of GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, routes, http-delete

I have a route I am issuing a `DELETE` on:

```
user_authorization_path(@user, authorization)
```

It hits my controller fine, the controller deletes the resource, and then issues a redirect:

```
redirect_to edit_user_path(params[:user_id])
```

The result of this is a routing error on redirect:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/1/edit")
```

I can see in the logs rails is doing the right thing until the redirect, which it is trying to issue another `DELETE` instead of a `GET`:

```
Started DELETE "/users/1/authorizations/12"...
...
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Started DELETE "/users/1/edit"...

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/users/1/edit")
```

The Chrome debugger shows the initial request:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/users/1/authorizations/12
Request Method:DELETE
Status Code:302 Found
```

And its following of the redirect:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/users/1/edit
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

So this appears to be that the browser is following the redirect correctly, but rails is ignoring the `GET` on the redirect call and instead using `DELETE` which results in 404 (since `DELETE` is not supported by that resource - which is wrong anyway).

If I simply do a 'GET' on the redirected URL, it works fine.

What am I missing about Rails' redirect after delete? Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should fix it in a nicer way:

`redirect_to edit_user_path(params[:user_id]), status: 303`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

> If you are using XHR requests other than GET or POST and redirecting
>   after the request then some browsers will follow the redirect using
>   the original request method. This may lead to undesirable behavior
>   such as a double DELETE. To work around this you can return a 303 See
>   Other status code which will be followed using a GET request.

Comment: Much better than changing the routes. At least someone reads the docs. Thank you!

Comment: You can use **:see_other** instead of **:303**. I think it's more readable.