# link_to executes child and parent delete action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in my project **Project is parent** and **Medium is Child**.
I want to delete one of the childs asynchronously (ajax / js.erb).

When clicking on this **link** (turbo_method is supposed to imply the asynchronous part of the request but I'm not sure about how it works.) something goes wrong.

```
<%= link_to "Delete Medium", project_medium_path(medium.project, medium), data: { turbo_method: :delete, turbo_confirm: 'are you sure ?' } %>
```

Here are my logs.

[image: console error]

My problem is that after deleting my media entity, **it also deletes my project entity**. The fact that deleting my project entity implies a **ForeignKeyViolation error is normal**, I haven't setup my model correctly yet. Either way, **it shouldn't delete my project entity**.

Here are my controllers, models and my views disposition :

> **Projects controller**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_project, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /projects
  def index
    @projects = policy_scope(Project).order(date: :desc)
    authorize Project
  end

  # GET /projects/1
  def show
    @medium = Medium.new(project: @project)
  end

  # GET /projects/new
  def new
    @project = Project.new
    # Set active user as project owner
    @project.user = current_user

    authorize @project
  end

  # GET /projects/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /projects
  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    # Set active user as project owner
    @project.user = current_user

    authorize @project

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_url(@project), notice: "Project was successfully created." }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /projects/1
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.update(project_params)
        format.html { redirect_to project_url(@project), notice: "Project was successfully updated." }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
  def destroy
    @project.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: "Project was successfully destroyed." }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:id])
      authorize @project
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit(:title, :slug, :subject, :category, :description, :location, :date, :user_id)
    end
end
```

> **Media controller**

```
class MediaController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_medium, only: %i[ edit update destroy ]
  before_action :set_project, only: %i[ create edit update ]

  # GET /media
  # def index
  # end

  # GET /media/1
  #def show
  #end

  # GET /media/new
  def new
    @medium = Medium.new
    authorize @medium
  end

  # GET /media/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /media
  def create
    @medium = @project.media.create(medium_params)
    authorize @medium

    respond_to do |format|
      if @medium.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_url(@medium.project), notice: "Medium was successfully created." }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /media/1
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @medium.update(medium_params)
        format.html { redirect_to project_url(@medium.project), notice: "Medium was successfully updated." }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /media/1
  def destroy
    @project = @medium.project
    @medium.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: "Medium was successfully destroyed." }
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_project
      @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
      authorize @project
    end

    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_medium
      @medium = Medium.find(params[:id])
      authorize @medium
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def medium_params
      params.require(:medium).permit(:title, :description, :author, :location, :date, :priority_index, :project_id, :visual)
    end
end
```

> **Project model**

[image: project model]

> **Medium model**

[image: Medium model]

[image: views]

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Here they are ! There is no dependent: :destroy or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598703/rails-redirect-after-delete-using-delete-instead-of-get).

Using `status: 303` inside **Media#Destroy** for the redirect_to method.