# Why is this Rails 7 link_to destroy nested resource also trying to destroy the parent resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

I have two models: `site`, and `heading`, site has_many headings.

I have a destroy link:

```
  <%= link_to site_heading_path(@site, @heading), data: { 'turbo-method': :delete, 'turbo-confirm': "Are you sure?"} do %>
    <i class="ti ti-trash"></i> Destroy
  <% end %>
```

Here's my headings controller method, it's basically just the stock action:

```rb
  def destroy
    @heading.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to site_path(@site), notice: "Heading was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

I've written this code a thousand times, but for some reason in my barebones new Rails 7 codebase it is doing something wonky.

### Expected:

Heading is deleted, i'm redirected to `/sites/1`

### Actual Behavior:

1. Heading is deleted (good)
2. I can see the redirect (good)
3. TURBO_STREAMS for some reason calls DELETE on `/sites/1` (very bad)

I have no idea why this would happen.

Here is the webrick output. You can see it tried to delete the site too. I don't know why..

[image]

Comment: strange indeed. Almost like with the redirect to site_path,  turbo-method: delete is being resubmitted?  I am still stuck on rails 6 :) but anyway you can verify the turbo method on the redirect from the network calls?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a new issue, here it is from 2013:

*[Rails Redirect After Delete Using DELETE Instead of GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598703/rails-redirect-after-delete-using-delete-instead-of-get)*

but, it became very relevant with *Turbo*. When redirecting from a javascript *DELETE* request, browsers will use *DELETE* for the redirected location. The solution is to use `303` redirect which will always be a *GET* request:

```rb
redirect_to site_path(@site), status: 303
redirect_to site_path(@site), status: :see_other
```

I guess this would count as documented:

*https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/drive#redirecting-after-a-form-submission*

> After a stateful request from a form submission, Turbo Drive expects
> the server to return an HTTP 303 redirect response, which it will then
> follow and use to navigate and update the page without reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Actually looks like this is a documented open issue on rails :)

https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/259

This comment on the above thread might help:

https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/issues/259#issuecomment-1013852530